# Serverless middleware not being called

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless

I'm working in a `serverless aws-nodejs` application. I'm trying to write an authentication middleware that checks for a session Cookie and appends a user id to the context. I'm using the `serverless-middleware` package as suggested on serverless.com docs. My implementation looks like this:

```js
handlers/user/authorize.js

async function handler(event, context) {
  let headers = {
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": event.headers.origin,
    "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": true
  }

  console.log("[Authorize]", "this is being run")

  let cookies = CookieParser(event.headers.Cookie)

  if(!cookies.session) return { statusCode: 401, headers, body: JSON.stringify("Unauthorized") }

  const decoded = jwt.decode(cookies.session, process.env.JWT_SECRET)

  console.log("[Authorize.decoded]", decoded);

  if(!decoded.id) return { statusCode: 401, headers, body: JSON.stringify("Unauthorized") }
  
  return { context: { user: decoded.id } }
}

module.exports.handler = handler;
```

I also have the primary handler:

```js
handlers/user/token.js

async function handler(event, context) {
  let headers = {
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": event.headers.origin,
    "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": true
  }
  
  console.log("[User.Token.event]", event)
  console.log("[User.Token.context]", context)

  return { statusCode: 200, headers, body: JSON.stringify("Success") }
}

module.exports.handler = handler;
```

This is put together in my `serverless.yml` file like so

```js
serverless.yml

functions:
  token:
    middleware:
      - handlers/user/authorize.handler
    handler: handlers/user/token.handler
    events:
      - http:
          path: /user/token
          method: get
          cors: true
```

Expected behavior - The console says "[Authorize]" this is being run. The response is a 401 status with "Unauthorized" body.

Current behavior - The authorize middleware is not being called at all and I only see the output of the `token.js` function.

Comment: Did you try moving the token handler underneath the middleware key as `- then: handlers/user/token.handler` like first example [here](https://www.serverless.com/plugins/serverless-middleware)?

Comment: Just tried and getting same behavior

Comment: I'd be tempted to debug this by unzipping the Lambda deployment package that serverless creates (or just download it from the Lambda console) and see what the code associated with the deployed handler function is actually doing.

Comment: @Ryne, have you got the solution , I am also facing same.